# Send Push Notification to all registered devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

I am working on parse push notification. I am facing one issue.Suppose one user login in ipad app and subscribe to channel x but he has not login to iphone.Now if we send notification on channel x it will only reach to iPad .So how we can send push notification to channel x for all registered device of user.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

1. Get the installations for the required channel.
2. Get the users for all those installations.
3. Get all installations for the users.

This will give you all the installations for the users where any installations has subscribed to the given channel.

Another (better?) way would be to write a cloud code script that updates all installations when a user subscribes to a channel.

So, when a user adds a channel to their iPad your script will find all the user's devices and update them all to the same channels.

Comment: Could you please write some code as i am new to parse ..thanks for reply